# How many Base64 characters fit in an Amazon SQS message?

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

I'm planning to use AWS' Simple Queue Service (SQS) to send Base64-encoded messages, and specifically using the official Java SDK, [aws-java-sdk-1.10.64](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk).

The [SendMessage API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html) says SQS messages can be up to 256K in length, which is a measure of bytes used. But the messages have to be strings containing characters in the character set

```
#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20 to #xD7FF] | [#xE000 to #xFFFD] | [#x10000 to #x10FFFF]
```

and all the Java APIs take normal `java.lang.String` objects as inputs. So the API is stating its input type in terms of a sequence of *characters* (a string) but stating its maximum message length in terms of *bytes*.

So my questions are:

1. How does SQS decide how many bytes a Java string occupies?
2. Where in the process (client-side API code? Server?) does SQS check the message length.

Comment: All the characters in the base64 alphabet are one byte wide in utf8 so it should be bytes == characters in that case.  When multi-byte characters are involved, the question becomes more interesting.  Validation has to be done at the server, regardless, since you can write your own client (as indeed I have done -- not a fan of the SDKs) but it's possible the client could do it to, though that would seem unnecessary.  I'll try to do some testing with my client library and see if I can come up with an interesting answer.  The SQS API documentation is dreadfully incomplete.

Comment: Base64, of course, represents a 4:3 expansion since each byte (character) carries only 6 bits of data, so the intuitive answer would be 192K bytes of payload before encoding in base64.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thank for the replies! I know that the Base64 alphabet is comprised of one-byte characters if UTF-8 encoded, but I'm curious where, if anywhere, the documentation or code shows that your Strings get UTF-8 encoded to be sent! It's not listed anywhere!